# What is the difference between Full-Duplex, Half-Duplex and Simplex TCP/IP operation?

Tags: tcp

Describe each mode.

Give examples of protocols that implement the various modes of TCP/IP operation.

Comment: My internet searches didn't provide good enough answers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, t computer programming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Full-Duplex allows for communication in either direction at any time.
An example is HTTP Pipelining.

Half-Duplex allows for communication in one direction at one time then can switch to the opposite direction.
An example is the POP3 Protocol (as well as FTP, NNTP, SMTP).

Simplex allows for communication in one direction only and doesn't allow switching directions.   This is sometimes specificed programmatically as Simplex Server or Simplex Client.

Comment: Wow, two guys named Kevin Driedger on SO - what a coincidence!

Comment: Interesting answer. Probably not what I'd have suggested from university or Cisco's material. Oh wait, this guy answered his own question. Which means it's probably made up. -1 for that. The ridiculousness of this question is the fact that TCP must be bi-directional in order to complete the 3-way handshake. TCP by its very nature uses sliding windows as it expects communications to be full-duplex and delayed.

Comment: @PP: Ya, I was a little curious about an example of simplex TCP :)

Comment: @PP: Feel free to make an answer not "made up"!

Comment: @Hamish, @PP: Read the SO FAQ please: "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question."

Comment: Neither POP3, FTP, NNTP, nor SMTP is a half-duplex protocol. It is basically futile to speak of protocols being half-duplex when they are layered over TCP, which is itself full duplex. A better example would be RS-232.

Answer (score 3):

A simplex line permits data to flow only in one direction. doesn't support switching direction.
A half duplex line can alternately send or receive data but only one at a time.
A full duplex line can send and receive data simultaneously.